# htaccess vs password protected directories

Tags: authentication, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, .htpasswd

I have to add a password protected zone to a site I am working on (using the .htpasswd file).  The thing is the whole directory structure it's being pointed at doesn't exist and is created through mod_rewrite.

Will it still work, or does the directory actually have to physically exist on the server?

Clarification:
While I may need to password protect the directory:
http://sitename/category/protected/

mod_rewrite translates this to:
index.php?category=category&directory=protected

So the actual directory *does not exist*.  Is it still protectable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the access rules to the apache config file (httpd.conf or similar) in a Directory or Location tag instead of adding it in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rules will ultimately point to some files in a directory on your system (unless they redirect users to some external location). The authentication setup should be on the underlying directory that will be accessed.

Comment: The directory doesn't exist, which is the issue.  mod_rewrite fakes the whole thing.

Comment: Your mod_rewrite redirects to your `index.php` file, so either put a `.htaccess` file next to it, or as Anders suggested put the configuration into the main apache config and either use `<Location>` to match urls or `<Directory>` to match directories on the filesystem or even `<Files>` to match index.php specifically. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html for more information.